# How to get phone's Camera Resolution using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, cross-platform, resolution

When I capture a picture using my **iPad1** it gives me an **image of 2592 x 1936**. In iPad's **Technical spec its given as 1024 x 768** and even in my mobile application I have tried to capture photo with these different parameters for height,width :

`width: window.screen.width, width: window.screen.availWidth, window.innerWidth , window.outerWidth`

**But all using all these ways gives me an image of either 1024 x 768 or 1080 x 1920.**
Actually I want to capture original picture with its highest resolution available in device using my Cross Platform Application.

I am working on DevExtreme + Cordova project and using this  [mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview](https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview) plugin for my Camera Activity.

I am not getting why its native camera captures image of 2592 x 1936 !? And how can I capture image of this resolution from my mobile application? Any help is appreciated.